# Unable to Create multiplel print pages for Long elements Using Page-Break Properties"

Tags: vuejs3

"I am facing an issue with printing in my Vue 3 application. When an element is too long for the page, I've attempted to use page-break properties to cut the content at the end of the page and continue on another page. However, the system does not seem to create an additional page at all. I have experimented with various page-break options applied to different elements, but none have yielded the desired result."

Feel free to let me know if you have any specific questions or if there's anything else I can help you with.